# "Cannot POST /dialog/authorize/decision" while implementing the OAuthorize example

Tags: node.js, heroku, oauth, express

I'm implementing OAuth 1.0a with the [OAuthorize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize) library. I'm following the [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize/tree/master/examples/express2) provided by the library.

I'm hosting my app at Heroku. Using the [test client](http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php) I'm able to `GET` a request token, and use it to `/dialog/authorize`:

```
Hi Bob Smith!

Samplr is requesting access to your account.

Do you approve?
```

When I press `Allow`, I get a `Cannot POST /dialog/authorize/decision`.

I've registered the endpoint in `app.js`:

`app.post('/dialog/authorize/decision', oauth.userDecision);`

Either I am missing something silly from the OAuthorize example or there is a fault in the way I'm handling the transaction.

`dialog.ejs`:

```
<form action="/dialog/authorize/decision" method="post">
  <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="<%= transactionID %>">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Allow" id="allow">
    <input type="submit" value="Deny" name="cancel" id="deny">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it does it do it when you run it locally? Is this specifically when it's running on Heroku?

Comment: Good question! Actually, I can't get the port open, so I can't use the test client to try it. I'll look into it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am struggling with the same issue :P

Comment: hey @major-mann, i don't know if you can see this but i was struggling with the same issue.  the error message appears because we are at the step in OAuth when the user should be redirected back to the referrer, or i.e. the original application.  we get this error message because there is no callback URL specified, and it should be specified in the user authorization phase.   the after that, if applicable we initiate a separate request for access token using the request token and verifier -- i'm stuck at this part now :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that I didn't provide a proper callbackURL in `server.userAuthorization` callback.

see https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize/blob/master/examples/express2/db/accessTokens.js#L10 and https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize/blob/master/examples/express2/oauth.js#L152

Comment: if you remember, can you explain what you meant by "didn't provide a proper callbackURL"?  Were you sending an invalid callback, or not sending one at all?  did you change the code in your second link?